# How to Convert pdf to EPS vector using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

How to Convert PDF or PS file to EPS with Editable text using Ghostscript dll

[image: ghostscript example]

Comment: can you provide a detailed description of your code/error/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Use the eps2write device, eg:

```
-sDEVICE=eps2write
```

See the documentation in ghostpdl/doc/VectorDevices.htm. Note that if your PDF contains graphics operations which PostScript does not support (eg transparency) then the EPS will contain an image, not vectors.